# NodeJs - Error while reading files using fs.createReadStream

Tags: node.js, file, node-modules, fs

I am trying to implement a feature to my web app where you can upload CSV files and insert data into Postgresql. I have made my app endpoint and written some code

```
    const router = require('express').Router()
    const uploadMid = require('./fileUpMid')
    const pool = require('./db')
    
    
    const fs = require("fs");
    const fastcsv = require("fast-csv");
    
    const upload = async (req, res) => {
        if (req.files === null) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
        }
    
        const file = req.files.file;
    
        file.mv(`${__dirname}/uploads/${file.name}`, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}` });
        });
    
        let persons = [];
        let path = __dirname + "/uploads/" +file.name;
    
        fs.createReadStream(path)
            .pipe(fastcsv.parse({ headers: true }))
            .on("error", (error) => {
                console.error(error.message);
            })
            .on("data", (row) => {
                persons.push(row);   
            })
            .on("end", () => {
                //remove head
                persons.shift();
    
                const q = "some query here";
    
                pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    
    
                    try {
                        persons.forEach(row => {
                            console.log(typeof row)
                            var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row));
                            var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
                            console.log(values)
                            client.query(q, values, (err, res) => {
    
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err.stack);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("inserted " + res.rowCount + " row:", row);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    } finally {
                        done();
                    }
                });
            })
        // fs.unlinkSync(path)
            
    }
    
    
    router.post('/file', uploadMid.single("file") ,upload)
    
    module.exports = router
```

Everything seemed to work fine, but when I try to upload a second file I awlways get an error on terminal

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'filename here with full path'

```
>- Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at: 
>- at internal/fs/streams.js:126:14
>- at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:180:23) {
>- errno: -4058,
>- code: 'ENOENT',
>- syscall: 'open',
>- path: 'filename here with full path'}
```

I know this is not a safe nor secure way to upload data but this app is intended to be run only locally. Even when the first file is upload successfully in DevTools console it logs

> GET  http://localhost:3000/uploads/filename     [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 8ms]

But the file is created with all its content on uploads directory.
Any tip for what to look for ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Going by the error here ("filename here with full path")
I've never defined an absolute path to `fs` functions without using `path.join`.
Can you try using `path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', file.name);`?

Comment: @ypahalajani   Sorry I didn't explained myself well. Whenever I have quoted "filename here with full path" was the error log I was facing. Thank you a lot the solution worked for me now I am facing some delays when inserting the second file but will keep trying. 
Again thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I've posted the answer below. Please mark it as the answer so that the community knows this is answered now.

Comment: Also, regarding the delay, there could be multiple factors causing it. Normally, when big file uploads happen, I suggest you send a successful response right away from the server stating that the file upload is in the queue and maybe implement a polling mechanism to check whether the upload was successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error *(Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'filename here with full path')*, here is the suggested way of defining paths in NodeJS apps using the `path` module.

```js
const path = require('path');

// Inside`upload` middleware
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', file.name);
```